# App not installed as app isn't compatible with your phone

Tags: android, mobile, sdk

I'm facing an issue with my mobile application that has been working well on most devices. However, some users who have updated their Android version to Android 14 are encountering installation problems. Here's a snapshot of the issue:

[app issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x7N8.png)

After researching online discussions, it appears that this may be related to an SDK version mismatch. Notably, Android has updated the minimum SDK version allowed to SDK 23. I want to highlight that my application is compiled using SDK version 28, and the target SDK version is set to 26.

Has anyone else experienced a similar problem or have insights into how to resolve this issue? I'd greatly appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="26"/>
```

build.gradle

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

String getAndroidPackageSourceDir() {
    String res = System.getProperty("user.dir");
     FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: res + '/..').include('android*deployment-settings.json');
     String json = tree[0];
     def inputFile = new File(json);
     def InputJSON = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text);
     res = InputJSON["android-package-source-directory"]
     return res;
}

String androidPackageSourceDir = getAndroidPackageSourceDir();

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
}

android {
    /*******************************************************
     * The following variables:
     * - androidBuildToolsVersion,
     * - androidCompileSdkVersion
     * - qt5AndroidDir - holds the path to qt android files
     *                   needed to build any Qt application
     *                   on Android.
     *
     * are defined in gradle.properties file. This file is
     * updated by QtCreator and androiddeployqt tools.
     * Changing them manually might break the compilation!
     *******************************************************/

    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion androidBuildToolsVersion

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src', 'java', androidPackageSourceDir + '/../padrao/android/src']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res', androidPackageSourceDir + '/../padrao/android/res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the compile/target api level of your application? Please share your build.gradle file.

Comment: It seems that that data resides in your gradle.properties file. Please share that as well.

Comment: It appears to be something generated by Qt Creator during compilation time. I couldn't find a file with this name in the project folder.

Comment: Without this, it will be hard to specifically say what the issue is. I would make sure your compile/target levels are set to API 34 (Android 14), as you mentioned that this happens on devices with this OS system version.